# Date difference in SQL

Tags: mysql, date

How can I get the number of second between NOW() and a date in the database.

Thanks.

Comment: For what RDBMS? Date and time functions are often not portable, so there's no generic answer. They *all* have manual pages for available date/time functions you can consult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function. (the [`TIMEDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) function has a upper limit of `838:59:59`)

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, DateColumn, NOW()) As Seconds
FROM table
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(Now(), yourDateTime)) From Table;
```

- [MySQL: Now()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp)
- [MySQL: TimeDiff-Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)
- [MySQL: TIME_TO_SEC-Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec)